# Pause within an item of an animated list in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, itemize, pause

I have a slide with an animated list. For one item, I want to uncover the second half of it only after a keypress. When I use `\pause`, I have to press twice, but nothing happens and the second half appears **with the next** item.

Minimal example:

```latex
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item click 1
  \item click 2 \pause{} should appear at 3
  \item click 4
\end{itemize}
```

Concretely, after 2 appears, the next click does seemingly nothing, then at 4 both "should appear at 3" and "click 4" appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve the desired behavior, use the `\uncover` command instead of `\pause`:

```latex
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item appears at 1
  \item appears at 2 \uncover<+->{appears at 3}
  \item appears at 4
\end{itemize}
```